# My prefix is myself

Tags: riddle, english, affix-riddle

> My prefix is myself,
>
> My suffix comes second in competitions,
>
> My infix is two mountains side by side,
>
> I am a competition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> IMO

My prefix is myself,

> I

My suffix comes second in competitions,

> O is the second letter of c**o**mpetitions

My infix is two mountains side by side,

> The letter M looks like two mountains side by side

I am a competition.

> The International Mathematics Olympiad

Comment: Wow, so fast! Congrats!

Comment: Solve my one now

Comment: @Deepthinker101 I have looked at yours and had a couple of ideas but have not figured it out yet